# Chai/Mocha immutable tests consistently failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, immutable.js

I'm working through the tutorial [here](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html) and finding that pretty much all but the first most elementary chai tests are failing for me. Here is the current example for a failing test

```
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';
import {expect} from 'chai';

import {setEntries} from '../src/core';

describe('application logic', () => {
    describe('setEntries', () => {
        it('adds the entries to the state', () => {
            const state = Map();
            const entries = List.of('Trainspotting', '28 Days Later');
            const nextState = setEntries(state, entries);
            expect(nextState).to.equal(Map({
                entries: List.of('Trainspotting', '28 Days Later')
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

and here is the code testing against:

```
import {List} from 'immutable';

export function setEntries(state, entries){
    return state.set('entries', entries);
}
```

here is the error message for the failure:

```
1) application logic setEntries adds the entries to the state:

      AssertionError: expected { Object (size, _root, ...) } to equal { Object (size, _root, ...) }
      + expected - actual

                 "size": 2
               }
             ]
           ]
      -    "ownerID": [undefined]
      +    "ownerID": {}
         }
         "size": 1
       }
```

I can't seem to find any meaningful documentation on what this error means, and don't see any other users of this tutorial mentioning similar issues. Any idea where this is choking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use regular equality checks against Immutable objects. Instead, use something like [`Immutable.is()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is):

```
import Immutable, {List, Map} from 'immutable';

...

expect(
  Immutable.is(nextState, Map({
    entries: List.of('Trainspotting', '28 Days Later')
  }))
).to.be.true;
```

Or even better, use [`chai-immutable`](https://github.com/astorije/chai-immutable):

```
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import chaiImmutable  from 'chai-immutable';

chai.use(chaiImmutable);
```

With the latter, your test case can stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You must add below codes beginning of your file.

```
 import chai from 'chai';
 import chaiImmutable from 'chai-immutable';

 chai.use(chaiImmutable);
```